# Windows 10 update broke Gummiboot

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, gummiboot

I never had a problem running Arch Linux alongside Windows in a dual boot on UEFI.

However, the Windows 10 update seems to have added a new partion so that the gummiboot configuration is not correct anymore and it drops me to an emergency shell.

It seems to expect `/` at `/dev/sda5` and `/home` at `/dev/sda6`, when in fact `/dev/sda6` is `/` and `/dev/sda7` is `/home`. How can I fix this from the emergency shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, using `/dev` identifiers for these purposes is generally a BadIdea™ since the disk letter can change (if you have more than one disk). See the Arch wiki entry on [persistent block device naming](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Persistent_block_device_naming).

Second, Gummiboot is a dead project and while it is still an option to use it, you should consider moving to `systemd-bootd` (which is actually just gummiboot but handled through systemd internally).

Finally, the solution to your actual issue: get a live cd and boot from it. Mount your partitions as needed and `chroot` into them. Then, modify the config in your `/boot` (or wherever you put your ESP if not there) and change the partition labels to the correct ones. Note that, if you were using UUIDs, this likely would not be an issue since the partition ids would not have changed.

Comment: @jasonwryan, you're my hero.

Comment: I do what I can... :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice! However I did not find the place where to change the sda5 for the identifier, neither in the live system, nor in the emergency prompt. Even when I create the boot entry directly in the UEFI (circumventing gummiboot completely) it still tries to load `/dev/sda5` instead of `/dev/sda6`.

Comment: On the live system after you chroot in, the configuration is in wherever your ESP is.

Comment: But the ESP is a whole partion with a huge amount of files. Which of those files do I need to edit? And I think I am already in the ESP when I get dropped to the emergency shell? And I noticed that the /etc/fstab is empty in my emergency shell, I tried to copy the one from root but it was gone after reboot.

Comment: The ESP should not have *that* many files. You need to edit whichever one you used to create Arch's configuration. It's typically ``$ESP/loader/entries/arch.conf``.

Comment: Ahh I finally found it and it worked, you are my hero too! I thought the ESP is the same one which I get dropped from the emergency shell but they are different.